# Hide PDF URL using JS

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php page . I need to make it hard for user to get direct download link.For this i need a js function which start downloading pdf after 10sec automatically after page load. I dont want to provide a download link at all.  Also I cant use onpageload . PDF must download.

Comment: Hiding an URL to protect the resource is not a good idea. You'd better to implement the 10 seconds delay on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the browsers will tell you where the downloaded file came from, i think you may want to mask the file itself behind a 'temporary' link with mod_rewrite or other custom parameters. You don't need to use JavaScript for this.

After then you can simply push the file with PHP similarly [like this solution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175).

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to hide a URL from an end user - All they need to do is use Fiddler 2, Firebug or similar tools to view the requested URL

Comment: Ah, you are correct, but only about JavaScript. But it's very possible with PHP ...

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious - the client has to retrieve a URL - Even if that was a PHP script, it's still visible to the client. Of course, the PHP script can retrieve the pdf from anywhere, generate it on-the-fly, throw a 500 error or do anything else it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Have your download page redirect to the PHP file that will download it. If it can download it, it will redirect the user back to the previous page, because the download doesn't have the right content type, although it could be just a plain .html file. You don't need Javascript to do this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://mysite/d.php?file=resume">
```

I recommend the [Smart File Download](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php), from zubrag.com, if you don't already have a PHP file specifically for downloading.

Comment: I know it cant be hide,  just wana make it more complex for average user . Just need a JS to auto start download after X num of sec of page load. I have a dedicated page for downland